# How to manage App Store into RHMAP?

Tags: rhmap

I would like to know how can I create and manage my App Store into RHMAP.
I am looking there and I could find the area specific to do it into the studio. Can someone give me a hand here?

Answer (score 1):

To create and manage your App Store into RHMAP you can go to `Admin >> Mobile App Management` area.

For more information check the section "4.2.4. Mobile App Management"[1] into Product Features documentation.

[1] - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_mobile_application_platform_hosted/3/html/product_features/product-features-administration-and-management#mobile-app-management